# Oracle String Conversion - Alpha String to Numeric Score, Fuzzy Match

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a lot of name data where the following events are happening:

In one stream the data is submitted as "Sung" and in the other stream "Snug" my initial thought to this was to convert Sung and Snug to where each character equals a number then the sums would be the same, so even if they transverse a character, I'd be able to bucket these appropriately.

The other is where in one stream it comes in as "Lillly" as opposed to "Lilly" in the other stream.  I'd like to figure out how to fuzzy match these such that I can identify them.  I'm not sure if this is possible in Oracle.

I'm working with many millions of data points and trying to figure out how to write these classification buckets such that I can stop having so much noise in my primary task of finding where people are truly different people as opposed to a clerical error.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A common measure for such distance is called Levenshtein distance ([Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)).  This measures the "edit" distance between two strings -- number of edit operations needed to convert one into the other.

That's the good news.  More good news is that Oracle even has an implementation in the [UTL_MATCH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm) library.

The bad news is that it is really, really expensive on millions of data points.  Unfortunately, I cannot help you there so much.  One idea is to determine which names are "close enough" because they already share a certain minimum number of characters.

Another method is to convert the strings to what they sound like.  That is called [soundex](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm).  You may be able to use the two together -- assuming your names are predominantly English (the soundex algorithm was invented by the US Census Bureau, so it would work best on names in America).

Comment: This is very interesting Gordon.  I'm curious if this distance can stop at the minimum discovery or if there is an easy way to do the close enough calculation?  I don't need to know all the permutations, but rather that Frankk has an extra k then stop or 5 of 6 characters match.  The transverse will be hard, because the strings are the same just different order, that's where I was hoping to do something like A -1, B -2, ... Z-26, sum of string are equal, though I imagine that would be insanely resource intensive.  Really interesting information thank you for sharing.

Comment: @user197240 . . . I am not aware of any implementation of a "partial Levenshtein" for Oracle.  One may exist, but I'm not aware of it.